# Modding a magic mouse or resurfacing glass

Tags: magic-mouse

I'm rather surprised, a quarter inch of glass on top of a wood desk prevents my mouse from working.  I tried putting a sheet of paper under the glass, hoping that would give the laser enough to bounce off of but was unsuccessful so I'm looking for a good idea to mod the mouse or resurface a section of the glass.

I heard about some people using window tint on the glass but I don't think that's a very good solution.  If I've got to resurface the glass I'm hoping to find some sort of spray-on enamel or something more permanent and resistant to wear than a thin layer of film.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not all mice work well on glass - this is a result of the sensor and lighting, and there's not all that much you can do about it.

As for the glass itself, window film on top of the glass (this simulated frosted glass) may do the trick. An easier and probably better way though, is to spend a few dollars on a mousepad.